# do I need knowledge of java programing to develop android games in unity 3d?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I want to learn android game development. I don't have any programing knowledge. So should I learn JAVA and eclipse to develop games for android.

Or should I learn Unity 3d. And is knowledge of java programing is necessary to develop android games in unity? Or knowledge of Javascript/UnityScript will do. Can I develop android games in unity with just JavaScript knowledge??

what are the benefits of unity over Java/eclipse and vice versa when talking of android game dev??

Comment: you'd be better off learning generic techniques. it's one thing to know how to do it in a particular language, but if you don't know the WHY of something, you'll be utterly lost when switching environments because all you know is the HOW.. and HOW only works in specific ways

Comment: If you're interested in Java in particular then JMonkey engine is similar to Unity but using Java instead of C#. However;  either are challenging and you may want to start with something a little smaller

Answer (score 1):

Unity 3D Mainly uses two Programming languages: `C#` and `Javascript`

Your Question is whether do you really need to know `Java` programming to develop games in `Unity3D`

> The Answer would be a YES and a NO

Yes because, If you have already studied Java, Programming in C# would be a lot easier.

If you search the web, most of the post comparing C# and java says that C# is somewhat similar to Java aside from both of them being Object Oriented.

No because, although they are somewhat similar C# is another programming language that **Evolve** from Java and Developers and apps today mostly use C# in developing android Applications.

Here is a quote from one of Microsoft's Documentation:

> Naturally, Java came before C#, and C# was not created in a vacuum. It is quite natural that C# learned from both the strengths and weaknesses of Java, just as Java learned from Objective-C, which learned from C. So, C# should be different than Java. If Java were perfect, then there would have been no reason to create C#. If C# is perfect, then there is no reason to create any new programming language. The job would then be done. However, the future is unclear, and both C# and Java are good object-oriented programming languages in the present, so they beg to be compared.
>
> It is important to note that not everything can be covered here. The
>   subject matter is simply too large. The goal is to give enough
>   information so as to help managers and software developers make a
>   better-informed choice about which language to use in certain
>   situations. Maybe some little language quirk in C# may make someone
>   choose Java. Maybe some blemish in Java will influence someone to pick
>   C#. Either way, this document will attempt to dive deep enough into
>   details to dig up some hidden treasures that aid in our goal.

For a more in depth explanation, here is a Documentation [on programming languages, comparing C# and Java](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms836794.aspx)

If you will be learning either `C#` or `Javascript` it is better to know what their differences are first.
Here is a post about [Syntax differences in C# and Javascript](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/12911/what-are-the-syntax-differences-in-c-and-javascrip.html)

For in depth tutorials
here is an Ebook on [Learning C# programming in Unity 3D](https://books.google.com.ph/books?id=CCMbBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA6&lpg=PA6&dq=what+programming+language+does+unity+3d+use&source=bl&ots=tTQIDdE5SJ&sig=cX5xFA4bd856loXzfaQhduwyx4M&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CGYQ6AEwC2oVChMI_oCt2dzfyAIVQqKUCh3FVQJP#v=onepage&q=what%20programming%20language%20does%20unity%203d%20use&f=false). You can also visit Unity3D's website for their own collection of [tutorials](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials).

Answer (score 0):

Android Game Development using unity involves learning C# or a butchered version of javascript(which i don't recommend). As apposed to using java with eclipse.

Advantages of unity
-HUGE amount of people use it, ie lots of examples. 
-Can port to other environment easily if you're careful about platform specific code.
-comes with most of the instructions you need

Advantages of Java/eclipse.
-maybe less people use it?(not sure as i use unity for the most part)
-AFAIK can not port to some environments(AKA Apple Devices)

Either way you need to learn a programming language, and both eclipse's java(not javascript) and Unity's c# are both popular and SIMILAR in a lot of ways, so after learning one it would not be too difficult to learn the other.  BUT just as the comment says, if your brand new to scripting, then it's better to learn generic information about how and why both languages work.

IMHO i would choose to use unity (but i'm very biased) i find that most problems have been gone over and answers are handily available. 
Hope this helps... let me know if you need further insight into unity.

Comment: Isn't is necessary to attach android SDK with unity and program the game in java for unity? Of just JS/C# programming will do and I will get final apk?

Comment: It is nessesary to attach the android sdk to unity to build to android, but you only use it as an external tool, the coding for unity is always done in C#, whether your coding for android or iphone or PC/Mac. You don't need to touch java to get the final APK from unity.